# "using" namespace equivalent in ASP.NET markup

Tags: asp.net

When I'm working with DataBound controls in ASP.NET 2.0 such as a Repeater, I know the fastest way to retrieve a property of a bound object (instead of using Reflection with the Eval() function) is to cast the DataItem object to the type it is and then use that object natively, like the following:

```
<%#((MyType)Container.DataItem).PropertyOfMyType%>
```

The problem is, if this type is in a namespace (which is the case 99.99% of the time) then this single statement because a lot longer due to the fact that the ASP page has no concept of class scope so all of my types need to be fully qualified.

```
<%#((RootNamespace.SubNamespace1.SubNamspace2.SubNamespace3.MyType)Container.DataItem).PropertyOfMyType%>
```

Is there any kind of `using` directive or some equivalent I could place somewhere in an ASP.NET page so I don't need to use the full namespace every time?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I believe you can add something like:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="RootNamespace.SubNamespace1" %>
```

At the top of the page.

Answer (score 7):

What you're looking for is the [@Import page directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb44kack(v=VS.80).aspx).